# GDAL - NetCDF to colorized raster

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, satellite, goes-16

I have a NetCDF file that is satellite imagery. I would like to convert it to a raster image, **with color**, using `gdal` on the command line.

Here is what I have so far:

```
gdal_translate -unscale NETCDF:"goes16-c13.nc":Rad ugly.tif
gdal_translate -ot Byte -of png ugly.tif bw.png
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -dstnodata -999.0 bw.png bwProj.png
```

However, the file created with the last command (`bwProj.png`) is black and white.

My question is this: **How can I colorize that black & white image?** Will I have to use a color table, e.g. `gdaldem color-relief -alpha bwProj.png colortable.txt colored.png`, or does the NetCDF file itself contain color data? If the latter is true, how do I map it to the output raster?

You can find all of the files I am using below. They are stored on GitHub, and all of these links lead to direct downloads.

[`goes16-c13.nc`](https://github.com/SteepAtticStairs/AtticRadar/raw/main/resources/soFiles/goes16-c13.nc) (the NetCDF file I am using)

[`bwProj.png`](https://github.com/SteepAtticStairs/AtticRadar/raw/main/resources/soFiles/bwProj.png) (the black and white image currently being produced)

[`GOES-16_C13.png`](https://github.com/SteepAtticStairs/AtticRadar/raw/main/resources/soFiles/GOES-16_C13.png) (an example of the color palette that I would like)

Comment: Does the dataset name `OR_ABI-L1b-RadC-M6C13_G16_ ...` imply a single band (C13)?

Comment: Yes, this is channel 13 for goes data.

Answer (score 0):

Ive inspected your netCDF data file and it looks like you have a 1 band (1 wavelength) image.

[image]

I then had the plot of variable "Rad" and here how it looks like looks like
[image]